# JavaScript regex test returns 'true' in console when there is clearly no match

Tags: javascript, regex, string-interpolation

I'm trying to do a simple test of a JavaScript regex I've written w/ ChatGPT's help (I know almost no JavaScript!). Here is the regex:

```
new RegExp(`(i'm [a-z]+ to ${I_OPINION_WORDS})`, 'i')
```

An exemplar expression is "I'm inclined to think..."

When I test it with a string that does not include "i'm" or "to" ("I think we should reconsider the language we use to discuss this.") the test returns true.
Could someone help me understand this behavior and, I'm guessing, change the regex to return false?

```js
const DONT_PHRASES = / dont| don't| do not| can not| cant| can't/;
const PRONOUNS = /he|she|it|they/i;
const PRESIDENT_NAMES = /candidate|clinton|donald|gop|hillary|hilary|trump|trum/i;
const SKIP_WORDS = / also| really| very much/;

const AMBIGUOUS_WORDS = /seemed|prefer/;
const I_OPINION_WORDS = /agree|believe|consider|disagree|hope|feel|felt|find|oppose|think|thought|support/;
const OPINION_PHRASES = /in my opinion|it seems to me|from my perspective|in my view|from my view|from my standpoint|for me/;
const OPINION_PHRASE_REGEXES = [
  new RegExp(`(i(?:${DONT_PHRASES}|${SKIP_WORDS})? ${I_OPINION_WORDS})`, 'i'),
  new RegExp(`(i'm [a-z]+ to ${I_OPINION_WORDS})`, 'i'),
  new RegExp(`(${OPINION_PHRASES},? )`, 'i')
];

const regex = new RegExp(OPINION_PHRASE_REGEXES[1]);
console.log(regex.toString())
console.log(regex.test("I think we should reconsider the language we use to discuss this."));
```

Comment: Could you please post a [mre] that doesn't get errors due to nonexistent variables?

Comment: when interpolating your regex you are getting something like `"i'm [a-z]+ to agree|believe|consider|...`. and here you can probably see better that "believe" is a suitable string, as well as "cosider" and "i'm qwerqwer to agree". put braces around your interpolation to make `|` work as you want `(?:${INTERPOLATION})`

Comment: I'd be using string not regexs to store the variables.  Your example reconsider will match with consider. You need to use word boundaris.

Comment: Asking for a fix for AI written code is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe what you're actually trying to achieve and *your* best try or understanding of the problem.

Comment: Also use something like Regex101 to test your regexes : https://regex101.com/r/wNlj2u/1

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex as part of the interpolation, use a string or something else, if you look at your console log of the generated regex it does not look correct.

You should also use a  tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regexes.

Next you need to use a grouping construct `()` for your alternates and use word boundaries (`\b`) as ***re*consider** matches **consider** in a regex without the word boundaries.

```js
/*Use an array to hold the words*/
const A_OPINION_WORDS = ["agree","believe","consider","disagree","hope","feel","felt","find","oppose","think","thought","support"];

/*Use join to generate the regex version, can be done in the string interpolation*/
const I_OPINION_WORDS = A_OPINION_WORDS.join("|");
/*Note the use of () for a capturing group and \b for word boundaries*/
const OPINION_PHRASE_REGEXES = [
  new RegExp(`(i'm [a-z]+ to \b(${I_OPINION_WORDS})\b)`, 'i') 
];

const regex = new RegExp(OPINION_PHRASE_REGEXES[0]);
console.log(regex.toString())
console.log(regex.test("I think we should reconsider the language we use to discuss this."));
```

What you really should take away from this is to always take AI generated code with a grain of salt and you need to look at what it has given you and work out what it is actually doing.